# Solve: $cis(\frac{\pi}{9})z^3=cis(\frac{\pi}{6})$

Tags: complex-numbers

> $$cis(\frac{\pi}{9})z^3=cis(\frac{\pi}{6})$$

$$e^{\frac{\pi}{9}i}z^3=e^{\frac{\pi}{6}i}\text{ \* }e^{-\frac{\pi}{9}}$$

$$z^3=e^{\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\pi}{9}i}=e^{\frac{3}{54}i}$$

$$z^3=e^{\frac{3}{54}i}$$

$$z^3=e^{\frac{3}{54}i+2\pi k}$$

$$z=e^{\frac{3}{3*54}i+\frac{2\pi k}{3}}$$  where $k=0,1,2$

$\{e^{\frac{1}{54}i},e^{\frac{1}{54}i+\frac{2}{3}},e^{\frac{1}{54}i+\frac{4}{3}}\}$

$\{cis({\frac{1}{54})},cis(\frac{1}{54}+\frac{2}{3}),cis({\frac{1}{54}i+\frac{4}{3}})\}$

Where have I got it wrong?

Answer (score -1):

the correct procedure is
$$e^{\frac{\pi}{9}i}z^3=e^{\frac{\pi}{6}i}\text{ \* }e^{-\frac{i\pi}{9}}$$
$$z^3=e^{\frac{i\pi}{6}-\frac{\pi}{9}i}=e^{\frac{\pi}{18}i}$$
$$z^3=e^{\frac{\pi}{18}i}$$
$$z^3=e^{\frac{\pi}{18}i+2\pi k} $$
$$z=e^{\frac{\pi}{3*18}i+\frac{2\pi k}{3}} $$
$$z=e^{\frac{\pi}{54}i+\frac{2\pi k}{3}} $$

where $k=0,1,2$
$$ \{e^{\frac{\pi}{54}i},e^{\frac{\pi}{54}i+\frac{2}{3}},e^{\frac{\pi}{54}i+\frac{4}{3}}\}$$
$$\{cis({\frac{\pi}{54})},cis(\frac{\pi}{54}+\frac{2}{3}),cis({\frac{\pi}{54}i+\frac{4}{3}})\} $$
$$ $$